# Game Center hasn't updated in about a week

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gamekit

For the past week or so, all the leaderboards in my app have been showing the same scores, and the same number of total scores in the 'All Time'/'This Week'/'Today' views.

There have definitely been new players since this point, and it started without any update to the app itself, so I'm pretty confident that its score-submitting code is sound. I have sent out a new update since, though none of the GameCenter-related code has changed. While four new leaderboards got approved along with the update, and are showing, they contain no scores.

Anybody else experiencing this? Or does anyone have any inclination of why it might be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, however my app is in TestFlight currently. The leaderboard code I am using is sound, and I am putting it into my own layout, so I'm fairly sure this is an Apple error. I have spent the last week trying to fix mine, but I think it is just Apple. Also, when it periodically works, it only shows GC friends, and you can't even add friends anymore so it's useless. (Could just be a TestFlight problem I'm having).

Comment: It's very weird! It doesn't seem like a TestFlight problem; I've had no problem seeing scores from TestFlight users in the past. Definitely seems like Apple's problem, so I hope it gets fixed soon!